# Aw, Snap! Google Chrome

Tags: chrome-for-android

I was in low coverage area for a week and was getting **"Aw snap"** error in google chrome. I'm using on android 4.0.4. But now when I back to full coverage area still getting Aw Snap error. I tried suggested solutions as if facing frequently but still occurring. Even I had reset my phone once and reinstall chrome though. Mostly error showing for specific sites. How do I can get rid of it? Or do I need to contact my carrier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Aww Snap crush is a bug in chromium caused by different things:

1. **Low memory**

   - It is also possible that site contains lots of images or JavaScript which might force Chrome to run out of space on the device while loading the site.
   - I'd suggest you clear up some space on the device and reboot the device.
   - If it helps, try closing any unused application in background to save resources  (CPU, RAM and disk space) and see if Chrome continues to crash.
2. **This vulnerability crashes browser tabs when encountering a  link with a malformed URL in the HTML of a page.**

   - The bug crashes the browser without the user taking any direct action other than loading the affected page.
   - This vulnerability occurs because of Chrome's habit of prefetching page data, such as performing DNS lookups on domain names in links on a page, in a preemptive attempt to speed up future loads. 
     Chrome will try and work out which link on a site you're likely to click on next and then pre-load in the background.
   - Possible fix is disabling pre-fetching
   - Go to Settings >> Privacy >> Use a prediction service to load pages more quickly >> Uncheck box.

   **3. Another possible cause is a corrupt profile.**

   - You can create a new profile, but if you do, custom data won't be available by default. This includes  bookmarks, extensions and settings that you may have changed in Chrome.

References:

1. [Aw, snap! How huge HTML links can crash Chrome tabs in one click](https://forums.theregister.co.uk/forum/1/2015/04/07/chrome_awsnap_vuln/)
2. [How to fix Google Chrome’s Aw, Snap! error message when loading websites](https://www.ghacks.net/2013/05/23/how-to-fix-google-chromes-aw-snap-error-message-when-loading-websites/)
3. [Constantly getting Aw Snap error in Chrome (Android)](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/4is6D8xRFnU)

Answer (score 0):

Just go to Recent apps menu where u clean up background processes and lock the Chrome app.
It solved the problem in my case.
Hope it does in your case too.